# "Swift is not supported for static libraries" when testing cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xctest

Recently I started creating my pod in Swift. I used `pod lib create` command and declined offer to use Nimble/Quick as testing library because I hoped to use standard XCTest. However, when I try to run tests, build just fails with message `Swift is not supported for static libraries`.

I tried to reopen Xcode and clean project, not working.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Swift don't supported static libraries. If you create lib used objc so you have 2 ways (create static lib and write script for convert to framework) but if you write used swift only one.

So you need create pod. Just create framework in xcode and add files for configurate your project to pod. It't easy, for example you can watch [this](https://github.com/ajjnix/SimpleKit/blob/master/SimpleKit.podspec), I create pod after create project

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I still not understand what to do. This project for which you gave the link is written in ObjC, so it's not relevant to my situation

Comment: "I used pod lib create" — "Just create framework in xcode and add files for configurate your project to pod". http://prntscr.com/b5h19s

Answer (score 0):

For swift you need to have Cocoa Touch Framework